# How to add resource-bundle to Spring-JSF application

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a spring-jsf integration app. When I try to get messages from resource-bundle at faces-config.xml, it runs without problem. But i want to move this resource bundle to spring applicationContext.xml but problem is, It couldnt find my resource bundle. Here is my faces-config;

```
    <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>

         <resource-bundle>
                  <base-name>/resources/locale/messages</base-name>
                   <var>msg</var>
         </resource-bundle>
         <locale-config>
                   <default-locale>es</default-locale>
                   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
                   <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
          </locale-config>

    </application>
</faces-config>
```

and my applicationContext.xml

```
        <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
    </bean>


<bean id="msg"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `<base-name>` element is incorrect.

```
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>Messages</base-name>
  <var>msgs</var>
</resource-bundle>
<locale-config>
  <default-locale>en_US</default-locale>
  <supported-locale>nl</supported-locale>
  <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
```

The base name of the resource bundle is the prefix of your properties file.  JSF is smart enough to determine the locales and derive the correct filename for the properties file off of your classpath.

Eg.

> Messages_en_US.properties
>
> Messages_es.properties

The excerpt above shows the default locale set as English with other supported locales listed below.  When a visitor with this preferred locale requests your JSF page it will be smart enough to retrieve the properties values from the approrpriately name resource bundle.

*[Taken from BalusC's Tutorial on Resource Bundles](http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/)*

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en_US</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>nl</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.example.faces.i18n.Text</base-name>
        <var>text</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

The other way that this can be done is to implement your own ResourceBundle class.

```
public class Text extends ResourceBundle {
```

Detailed instructions on how to do this are listed at the linked tutorial.

The added benefit of implementing your own resource bundle is that you can declare this as a Spring bean with Application Scope and through DI can push it to other code throughout your application in case you need to access various resource bundle properties in code.